# Google Chrome Portable vs. Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, lag

Is there any advantage/disadvantage of using the Google Chrome Portable app for PC (apart from it being portable)?

In addition, I have had Google chrome on my PC installed for quite a while recently installed and I have noticed a slight instability (by instability I mainly mean lags) in my original Chrome browser that might be related with me having them both installed simultaneously (keep in mind that they both sync all my data associated with my Google account and that I have extensions installed under my Google account that run even with Chrome shut down!).

**Edit:**
Basically, I would prefer the portable chrome, but what i want to know, is whether it comes at a cost!

Comment: I don't believe the Portable App version will update automatically, which could be seen as a good or a bad thing . . .

Comment: No not by itself but the PortableApps.com Platform™ is a full-featured portable software menu, backup utility, app store, **automatic updater**...([PortableApps.com Platform™](http://portableapps.com/download) )

Comment: Maybe it would help the question if you detailed what you consider to be advantages and disadvantages. Otherwise this might get more opinionated answers than it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)

> Passwords Not Saved Between PCs By Default: Google Chrome stores passwords in such a way that they are encrypted in a way tied to current PC. While the passwords are not kept or left behind on the PC itself, they won't be retrievable when you move to a new PC. We've added password portability as an advanced option, though, which you can enable by reading the help.html file.
>
> Certificates Not Portable: Google Chrome has no certificate manager. It uses Windows' certificates manager. So, any certificates you install through the Google Chrome interface are stored on the current local machine and will not travel with you. Thus, you should not use any private certificates with Google Chrome except on your own PC.

The portable version may create folders at it's file location i.e. Desktop to start storing it's cache, add-ons also.

Comment: I have heard of website certificates but what do you mean by private certificates for my browser? Also can you clarify as to where it stores its cache and addons? I have not noticed any file generation outside the actual portable chrome folder itself!

Comment: Rather than copying paragraphs of text and pasting them in your answer as if they were your own words, remember to use the formatting tools *above* the text block to indicate you are quoting something, and give credit as to where the quotes were from.